# How to replace values in a column for a specific condition?

Tags: r

I want to change the orders to 100 if my revenues > 1900 and the day is not "sun"
Can someone please help. Any help will be appreciated.

my data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", 
"sun"), orders = c(90L, 80L, 50L, 20L, 5L, 20L, 95L), revenues = c(1800L, 
2000L, 1000L, 2000L, 100L, 400L, 1900L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Day1", 
"Day2", "Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6", "Day7"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(orders = ifelse(revenues > 1900 & day != "sun", 100, orders))
```

```
     day orders revenues
Day1 mon     90     1800
Day2 tue    100     2000
Day3 wed     50     1000
Day4 thu    100     2000
Day5 fri      5      100
Day6 sat     20      400
Day7 sun     95     1900
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a logical vector and use that index to do the assignment

```
i1 <- with(df1, day != 'sun' & revenues > 1900)
df1$orders[i1] <- 100
```

-output

```
> df1
     day orders revenues
Day1 mon     90     1800
Day2 tue    100     2000
Day3 wed     50     1000
Day4 thu    100     2000
Day5 fri      5      100
Day6 sat     20      400
Day7 sun     95     1900
```

Comment: But this is making all orders 100 ;(

Comment: @ShubhamPatil the `i1` based on the logic gives `i1#
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`. So, not clear about your comment

Comment: @ShubhamPatil I would check the `str(df1)` in your original dataset.  Maybe your column `revenues` is not `numeric` class?

Comment: revenues is numeric , please see below

'data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ day     : Factor w/ 7 levels "fri","mon","sat",..: 2 6 7 5 1 3 4
 $ orders  : num  100 100 100 100 100 100 100
 $ revenues: num  1800 2000 1000 2000 100 400 1900

Comment: @ShubhamPatil Try the `i1 <- with(df1, as.character(day) != 'sun' & revenues > 1900)` though it shouldn't matter with `factor` column